# How to store huge integers in swift? And what the criteria for using type UInt64 instead of Int?

Tags: swift, memory, integer

As reading a documentation from Swift, It mentioned this:

> The number property of the CreditCard class is defined with a type of UInt64 rather than Int, to ensure that the number property’s capacity is large enough to store a 16-digit card number on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48

As a kid in scripting language and hardware, I wondered why use the UInt64 type to store the 16-digit credit card value, instead of the Int type. What is happening under the hood in memory when specify an Int type that difference to memory when using 64Int? What the maximum an Int or 64Int can store?

```
var number:Int=9999999999999999999999999999
```

The code above gives error says the integer literal overflowed.
But when I change to

```
var number:UInt64=9999999999999999999999999999
```

It also prints error says the same.

Comment: [`UInt64`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint64) is "A 64-bit unsigned integer value type", which means that it can hold non-negative values up to 2^64-1 = 18446744073709551615.

Comment: I think you should ask only one question per question. Either  ask `How to store huge numbers?` or `When to use (U)Int vs (U)Int64?`.

Answer (score 0):

An `Int` will always take the largest available integer type on the device your code is compiled for. What this means is that if your code is compiled for a 32-bit device (such as all iPhones up to and including the iPhone 5 or the first Apple Watch), `Int` will actually be represented as `Int32`, while on a 64-bit device, `Int` will be `Int64`.

You can easily check that a 16 digit credit card number can indeed overflow an `Int32` by comparing the largest possible credit card number to `INT32_MAX` or `Int32.max` (the maximum representable value of `Int32`), then you can also do the same for `UInt32`, `Int64` and `UInt64`.

```
let biggestSixteenDigitNumber = 9999_9999_9999_9999
biggestSixteenDigitNumber > INT32_MAX //true
biggestSixteenDigitNumber > UINT32_MAX //true
biggestSixteenDigitNumber > INT64_MAX //false
biggestSixteenDigitNumber > UINT64_MAX //false
```

As you can see, an `Int64` would actually be sufficient for storing 16 digit credit card numbers, but since a credit card number cannot be negative, it makes more sense to store it as `UInt64`.

Comment: You can simply  use `.max` static property on the types instead. `Int.max` or `Int32.max` and so on. Note that `Int.max` can be 32 or 64 depending on the device it is being used

Comment: You're right, I should've used `INT32_MAX`, for some reason XCode showed the type of `INT_MAX` as `Int32` in a playground. Thanks for the tip about the `.max` static property, didn't know about that.

Comment: Your introduction (as I understand it) is a bit misleading. What `Int` is is determined at *compile time,* not at runtime. An app compiled for the iPhone 4S has 32-bit ints, even if running on an iPhone X.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the correction, I didn't even think about this, since usually the device a code is compiled for and run on is the same, but you are right, the distinction between compile time and runtime decisions is important.